# 2 CSS divs: Allow sortable items in (right) div to create new sortable row instead of (right) div clearing other (left) div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a container with 2 divs inside:

One is a small fixed width left div that is floated to the left (like a side menu).
The second is a fluid div that also floats left (to be able to stack alongside the fixed div).

The second div has sortable icons that float left.  When the window is shrunk, I would like the icons to shift to the left and form a new row. For example, if "X" is an icon inside of the window and I have 6 icons.. My sortable items look just like the example here (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) except that they float and stack to the left instead of vertically, like in the example.

Before window shift (all stacked in one row because they fit the browser):

X X X X X X

After window shift (when only 4 can fit the shrunken browser, the other two should make a new row):

X X X X

X X

You can see the code here: jsfiddle.net/6ZWq6/18

My problem is that the right fluid column will clear the left fixed column and end up completely beneath it, then only after they are stacked on top of each other, will it start to form new sortable rows.  I do not want the right column to clear the left one at all, I just would like for the sortable items to make a new row.

I tried setting clear to none on the second fluid div and it did not change this behavior. I also tried floating the fixed column left and the fluid column right and it did not change it either.  Is there some way to make the sortable JS function occur before the clearing one or to completely prevent it from clearing?

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
.container
{
background: transparent;
overflow: hidden;
    clear: none;
}

.left-fixed {
background: #ccc;
padding: 10px;
width: 160px;
float: left;
min-height:500px;

}
.right-fluid {
list-style: none;
padding: 10px;
width: auto;
float: left;
overflow: auto;


}
.sortable-item {
cursor: move;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
color:#CC0033;
margin: 5px;
float: left;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="left-fixed connectedSortable" style="float:left"> 
        <div class="sortable-item"><span class="img1"></span>
        <p>Item Name Here</p>
        </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="right-fluid connectedSortable" style="float:left"> 
        <div class="sortable-item"><span class="img2"></span>
        <p>Item Name Here</p>
        </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.right-fluid, .left-fixed').sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

could you check this fiddle link, you may get answer

```
$(function() {
 $( "div.right-fluid" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".connectedSortable"


});
$( "div.left-fixed" ).sortable({
 connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
   dropOnEmpty: false 
});

 $( ".right-fluid, .left-fixed" ).disableSelection();
});



.container{background: transparent;overflow: hidden; clear: none;}

.right-fluid {padding: 10px;background: #ccc;width: 160px;float: left;
 min-height:500px;overflow: auto;}
.left-fixed {list-style: none;padding: 10px;width: 160px;float: left;}
.sortable-item {cursor: move;display: block;font-weight: bold;color:#CC0033;
 margin:5px;float: left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZWq6/10/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZWq6/18/
I added in some pictures for a sample inside the code you put in there. It is stuck on the bottom. Do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: I updated your existed fiddle file to resolve the picture issue, review this link http://jsfiddle.net/6ZWq6/28/. This will be useful for you.Also widht and height problem there, it might be due to large image size.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Philip Tenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463196/philip-tenn) for helping me fix the CSS, this ended up being the solution!

CSS change to:

```
.left-fixed {

    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    min-height:500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.right-fluid {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 160px;
}
```

The working code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ptenn/6ZWq6/19/

Answer (score 0):

could you try with this code

```
 $(function() {
  $( "div.right-fluid" ).sortable({
   connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  });
  $( "div.left-fixed" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    dropOnEmpty: false
  });
  $( ".right-fluid, .left-fixed" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for offering that! But, it still clears the right fluid div beneath the left fixed div when I shrink the window before it will sort new rows.